# HTMLs not found by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to write a program, that downloads the most upvoted picture from a subreddit, but for some reason the BeautifulSoup does not find all the links on a website, I know I could try it with other methods but I'm curious why isn't it finding all the link every time.

Here is the code as well.

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/top/'
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text,'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print (link.get('href'))
```

Comment: requests module will not be able to render `JavaScript`

Comment: I know, but sometime it find them, and other times does not. Beside the page I want to get the requests from is HTML.

Comment: edit your question. limit it to the end goal. show the desired output.

Comment: Something like this: https://imgur.com/6kvo4sq

Comment: @Pilv _edit your question_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site is loaded with `JavaScript`, `bs4` will not be able to render `JavaScript` therefor, I've been able to locate the `data` within `script` tag.

```py
import requests
import re
import json

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
}

def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    match = re.search(r"window.___r = ({.+})", r.text).group(1)
    data = json.loads(match)
    # print(data.keys())
    # humanreadable = json.dumps(data, indent=4)


main("https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/top/")
```

Shorter version:

```py
match = re.finditer(r'permalink":"(.+?)"', r.text)
for item in match:
    print(item.group(1))
```

Output:

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv9ubr/khyber_pakhtunkhwa_pakistan_balakot_1920x1024/
https://www.reddit.com/user/wsopgame/comments/fvbxom/join_the_official_wsop_online_poker_game_and/
https://www.reddit.com/user/wsopgame/comments/fvbxom/join_the_official_wsop_online_poker_game_and/?instanceId=t3_p%3DgAAAAABeiiTtw4FM0zBerf9DDiq5tmonjJbAwzQb_UwA-VHlw2J8zUxw-y6Doa6j-jPP0qt05lRZfyReQwnLH9pN6wdSBBvqhgxgRS3uKyKCRvkk6WNwns5wpad0ijMgHwqVnZSGMT0KWP4WB15zBNkb3j96ifm23pT4uACb6cpNVh-TE05GiTtDnD9UUMir02Z7hOr0x4f_wLJEIplafXRp2yiAFPh5VzH_4VSsPx9zV7v3IJwN5ctYLfIcdCW5Z3W-z3bbOVUCU2HqqRAoh0XEj0LrgdicMexa9fzPbtWOshfx3kIazwFhYXoSowPBRZUquSs9zEaQwP1B-wg951edNb7RSjYTrDpQ75zsMfIkasKvAOH-V58%3D   
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv6wew/lone_road_in_nowhere_arizona_1920x1080/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvaqaa/the_hobbit_house_1920_x_1080/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvcs4j/something_i_made_in_illustrator_5120_2880/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv09u2/bath_time_in_rocky_mountain_national_park_1280x720/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fuyomz/up_is_still_my_favorite_film_grandpa_carl_cams/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvagex/beautiful_and_colorful_nature_wallpaper_1920x1080/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv3nnn/maroon_bells_co_photo_credit_to/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fuyg0z/volcano_lightening_19201080/    
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvgohk/doctor_strange1920x1080/        
https://www.reddit.com/user/redditads/comments/ezogdp/reach_your_audience_on_reddit/
https://www.reddit.com/user/redditads/comments/ezogdp/reach_your_audience_on_reddit/?instanceId=t3_p%3DgAAAAABeiiTt9isPY03zwoimtzcC7w3uLzUDCuoD5cU6ekeEYt48cRAqoMsc1ZDBJ6OeK1U3Bs2Zo1ZSWzdQ4DOux21vGvWzJkxNWQ14XzDWag_GlrE-t_4rpFA_73kW94xGUQchsXL7f4VkbbHIyn8SMlUlTtt3j3lJCViwINOQgIF3p5N8Q4ri-swtJC-JyEUYa4dJazlZ9xLYyOHSvMkiR3k9lDx0NEKqpqfbQ9__f3xLUzgS4yF4OngMDFUVFa5nyH3I32mkP3KezXLxOR6H8CSGI_jqRA4dBV-AnHLuzPlgENRpfaMhWJ04vTEOjmG4sm4xs65OZCumqNstzlDEvR7ryFwL6LeH02a9E3czck5jfKY7HXQ%3D
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fuzjza/ghost_cloud_1280x720/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvg88o/park_autumn_tress_wallpaper_1920x1080/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv47r8/audi_quattro_s1_3840x2160_fh4/  
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fuybjs/spacecrafts_1920_x_1080/        
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv043i/dragonfly_1280x720/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv06ud/muskrat_swim_1280x720/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvdafk/natural_beauty_1920x1080/       
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvbnuc/cigar_man_19201080/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvcww4/thunder_road_3840_x_2160/       
https://www.reddit.com/user/redditads/comments/7w17su/interested_in_gaining_a_new_perspective_on_things/
https://www.reddit.com/user/redditads/comments/7w17su/interested_in_gaining_a_new_perspective_on_things/?instanceId=t3_p%3DgAAAAABeiiTtxVzGp9KwvtRNa1pOVCgz2IBkTGRxqdyXk4WTsjAkWS9wzyDVF_1aSOz36HqHOVrngfj3z_9O1cAkzz-0fwhxyJ_8jePT3F88mrveLChf_YRIbAtxb-Ln_OaeeXUnyrFVl-OPN7cqXvtgh3LoymBx3doL-bEVnECOWkcSXvUIwpMn-flVZ5uNcGL1nKEiszUcORqq1oQ32BnrmWHomrDb3Q%3D%3D
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv3xqs/social_distancing_log_1920x1080/
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvbcpl/neon_city_wallpaper_19201080/   
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fvbhdb/sunrise_wallpaper_19201080/     
https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/comments/fv2eno/second_heavy_bike_in_ghost_recon_breakpoint/
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know why the bs doesn't work as needed.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm really sorry, I'm not so familiar with 're' so I don't know what am I supposed to do with this. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @Pilv well actually I've used `regex` which you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html). Otherwise if you don't want to use `regex`, So you can will need to search for `window.___r ` and then parse what inside it. `split`, `[slice]` or whatever